# Design the output with awk or gawk script

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a awk script which give me the result i want on a .txt file but my concern is how the result is given: I have all of them in a single line and i want to design it.

```
20140201 -73828274 20140202 7376288374 20140203 3837482437 ....... 20140228 -73629277
```

I want the output to be displayed in this format

```
20140201          -73828274
20140202         7376288374
20140203         3837482437
n                  n
n                  n
n                  n
20140228           73629277
```

I want date one side and the corresponded total in front of the date

Here the awk script used

```
$ for file in *.txt;do awk -F,'NR==1{header=$0; next} {a[$1]+=$6+$14} END {for (i in a) {print i, a[i]};}' $file; done > red.txt
```

ANY IDEA ?

Comment: It is basically how you print the output. Can you share the script so that we can suggest the changes ?

Comment: @KannanMohan I added the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `print` you can use `printf`. Change the `END{}` part of your `awk` script as follows:

```
END {for (i in a) {printf "%d\t%d\n", i, a[i]};}
```

Between the two values (`%d`) it prints a tab (`\t`) and at the end a newline (`\n`).

Or your complete command:

```
for file in *.txt;do awk -F,'NR==1{header=$0; next} {a[$1]+=$6+$14} END {for (i in a) {printf "%d\t%d\n", i, a[i]};}' $file; done > red.txt
```

Comment: It works fine on the shell but when printed on the txt file i still have the same issue

Comment: You have the same issue because the issue has nothing to do with your awk script. It's whatever you are doing to display the contents of your file.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` and `tr` like below,

```
$ grep -oP '\S+\s+\S+' file | tr ' ' '\t'
20140201    -73828274
20140202    7376288374
20140203    3837482437
20140228    -73629277
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a shell loop, awk is perfectly capable of working on multiple files, e.g. with GNU awk for ENDFILE and delete array:

```
awk -F, 'FNR>1{a[$1]+=$6+$14} ENDFILE{for (i in a) print i, a[i]; delete a}' *.txt > red.txt
```

The above is obviously untested since you didn't provide any sample input.

The script you posted CANNOT produce the output you show though. There is something else you are doing after the awk script runs to make it appear to you as if all lines of your output file are on a single line. I suspect you are probably not quoting a variable again (like you didn't quote `$file` in your script) and doing something like:

```
var=$(cat red.txt)
echo $var
```

Once your script is done running simply do `cat red.txt` and you will see that the content is NOT all on one line as you claim.

Answer (score 0):

Her is a simple way to do it with `awk`

```
awk -v RS=" " 'ORS=NR%2?RS:"\n"' file
20140201 -73828274
20140202 7376288374
20140203 3837482437
```

First we sett Record Selector to space, so every date is a new line.
Then we change the Output Record Selector to space or newline based on odd and even line number.

---

You can also use the `getline` with this, but take care, `getline` has many pitfall.

```
awk -v RS=" " '{a=$0;getline;print a,$0}' file
20140201 -73828274
20140202 7376288374
20140203 3837482437
```

This way you can have more control of the output using `printf`

Comment: It's okay on the shell! I have the design i want but when i want that output on a txt file i still have all elements on a single line awk -v RS=" " '{a=$0;getline;print a,$0}' file > output.txt "THIS IS THE SCRIPT I USED"

Comment: It's okay i fixed it :)